# How to show that $\sum_{\rho} 1/|\rho| = \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

Just after Theorem 10.13 in the book Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory by Hugh Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan the following two statements are assumed to be without proofs. Perhaps they are simple to prove but I have no idea of the proofs:

Since $N(T) ≪ T \log T$ then $\sum_{\rho} |\rho|^{-A} < \infty$ for all $A>1$ and $\sum_{\rho} 1/|\rho| = \infty$. Here $N(T)$ is the number of zeros of the Riemann zeta function in the rectangle $0<\sigma <1$  and $0<\tau<T$, and $\rho$'s are zeros of zeta function. How to prove these two claims? Hints also would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: Have you tried partial summation?

Comment: @dummy there is "partial summation" in the book but not useful for this problem. How number of zeros is related to zeros?

Comment: Use Abel's summation formula.

Comment: @Ali "How number of zeros is related to zeros?" The number of zeros is $\sum_\rho 1$, basically :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of partial summation. Note that
$$\sum_{\rho} |\rho|^{-A} = \lim_{T \to \infty} \sum_{0 < Im(\rho) < T} |\rho|^{-A} = \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T t^{-A} d N(t).$$
Integration by parts shows that this equals
$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{N(T)}{T^A} + A\int_0^T \frac{N(t)}{t^{A+1}} dt.$$
Since $N(T) \ll T \log T$, if $A > 1$ we have
$$\frac{N(T)}{T^A} = O\left(\frac{\log T}{T^{A-1}}\right) \to 0$$
as $T \to \infty$ and
$$\frac{N(t)}{t^{A+1}} = O\left(A \frac{\log t}{t^A}\right)$$
is integrable as $t \to \infty$. Hence
$$\sum_{\rho} |\rho|^{-A} = A\int_0^{\infty} \frac{N(t)}{t^{A+1}} dt$$
is finite.

Note that $\sum_{\rho} |\rho|^{-1} = \infty$ does not follow from $N(T) \ll T \log T$ (Pretend for a moment that Riemann zeta function has finitely many zeros, then $N(T) \ll T \log T$ is of course true but $\sum_{\rho} |\rho|^{-1}$ converges). You would need $N(T) \asymp T \log T$ for that claim.

Comment: I understood your proof but still confused how some oof positive numbers is zero!

Comment: Oops, not sure what I was thinking. Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)